# showing multiple items inside listview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I was wondering if there is a way to show multiple elements inside listview.view.

SampleCode (which doesnst work)

```
            <ListView
                x:Name="Somename"
                ItemsSource="{Binding someObservableCollection}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <TextBlock></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock></TextBlock>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Column 1" >
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Column 2">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

Sample Data properties for a person.
Name
Age
Id
OldData1
OldData2
OldData3
NewData1
NewData2
NewData3

I am trying to show Name, age, Id and 3 textblocks
and then in a grid, compare olddata vs new data.

I tried doing with itemtemplate and then doing stackpanel with grid inside, but that grid looks very basic and would prefer gridview since it looks better.

[image]

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the issue is that you cannot have a single `DataTemplate` with multiple `GridView` instances contained within. Is that right? Why not just style your `Grid` to look like the `GridView` you like? The question is pretty broad as stated.

Comment: and you couldn't do this using ItemTemplate?

Comment: What is your question exactly? What does not work? What are you getting with your solution and what are you expecting?

Comment: "but that grid looks very basic and would prefer gridview since it looks better. "

What grids are we dealing with here ?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Yup, you are right, I did try to google how to style grid like gridview but nothing relevant came up.

Comment: @ChrisW. Could you elaborate more with itemtemplate? Itried using gridview inside itemstemplate and its not allowing me.

Comment: @dymanoid I am trying to achieve to have some textboxs and a gridview inside listview. At this point, I can only have textboxs or a gridview inside. I get error view can be only set once if i add textboxes and gridviewview.

Comment: @sylar: AFAIK, the easiest way to get the style information for the `GridView` is to go ahead and add one to some XAML in Visual Studio/Blend, then right-click on it in the Design mode and choose "Edit Template/Edit a Copy...". VS will automatically write out the template for that element as a resource in the window's resources; you can then use that template as your guide for the `Grid` objects you want to add to your `GridView`. I haven't bothered to check the results myself, but it's likely there would be a style for the `Grid` itself that you can just copy verbatim as the style for yours.